# get distinct values using Rest Api

Tags: rest, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get the distinct values from below code .But I find no luck to move further.

Can any one let me know what's wrong in my below code. Because I am trying to group the information to get distinct values.

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Title Values</td>
 <td>Month Values </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
       <select id="drbprogrames" class="select">
        <option selected="selected">Select</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  <td>
     <select id="drbmonths" class="select">
     <option selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', startfucntions);

function startfucntions()
{
 gettitleValues();
 getMonthValues();
}
function getMonthValues()
{

alert("Helo");
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tabletop%20Sessions')/items?$Select=Month",
type: "GET",
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
},
success: function (data) {
var result  = data.d.results;  // Get the results
var monthvalues = groupBy(items,'Title');
$('#drbprogrames').append(monthvalues);
},
error: function (error) {
alert(JSON.stringify(error));

}
});


}
```

Comment: I had implemented the same groupby function , In my above post

Comment: @MSA you are creating so many questions, please close the previous ones by selecting the correct answer

Comment: remove this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` and check. You are referencing jquery twice.